# Scam - how to kill a contract created by myself to get funds back?

Tags: remix

I think I got scammed because I deployed code that I didn't fully understand.

I created a contract by myself and transferred 1 BNB to it... Is there any chance to get that BNB back? It is still in the contract and the code looks as follows:

https://pastebin.com/raw/fktGNr2k

I read that if you kill the contract it might be possible to get the BNB back.

Looking very much forward to your support! If we find a solution I would like to share some of the BNB with you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code. Whatever you do, do not execute the "action" function. This will send the funds to the scammer's address: [0x1e90cd02d5f262e8b515170e6610227a7d8f6aab](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1e90cd02d5f262e8b515170e6610227a7d8f6aab).

Since the contract you deployed has no selfdestruct- or withdraw functionality your BNB is lost. Sorry for that. Stay safe!