# How were tokens withdrawn from this wallet without having the private keys?

Tags: etherscan

Case beyond my knowledge.
There is a wallet on Ledger. [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x678fd7e4d444b9c56d5eeb09454394f4d3313a8e58c613b4ca4e71756626ee1f) reports a successful transaction of some fake coin FROM this wallet. The amount of coins is non-zero.
No action has been taken with the Ledger hardware wallet at this time.
My knowledge is clearly not enough to understand how this can happen.
How is it possible to successfully withdraw coins (even fake ones) in a non-zero amount without private keys?
More precisely: How could such a transaction get the status “Success” in etherscan.io?

Comment: Could you please include the etherscan link and any other relevant information you may have?

Comment: [link]https://etherscan.io/tx/0x678fd7e4d444b9c56d5eeb09454394f4d3313a8e58c613b4ca4e71756626ee1f
My wallet among 200 others under "ERC-20 Tokens Transferred"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

The only way for a user to take funds from an account without the private key would be if the account has signed a transaction that does so.

After looking at the Etherscan link you provided, I can see that the contract that took the funds is known as `Fake_Phishing`, this leads me to believe that you may have accidently signed a malicious transaction at some point that allowed another user to steal your funds.
[image]

The extension I am using that references the contract as `Fake_Phishing`, is called [MetaDock](https://github.com/blocksecteam/metadock). It adds new features to block explorers to help users understand contract structure and layout easily.

Answer (score 0):

If the token contract has a transferFrom function that doesn't do any sort of allowance check, they could just call transferFrom.

Was a recent example of a token like that, pond0x
[image]

Where people were just repeatedly transferring from each others accounts.

---

Tokens usually carry a check. Like this from weth9:
[image]

---

If the token has a check like that and they are still removed from a wallet, the signer at some point signed an allowance for that to happen.
Possibly to a contract that was exploited after the fact, as in the case of the multichain hack.