# 0 balance after token swap

Tags: bsc, bscscan

Need some help with my recent transaction. After swapping some bnb for a token, the balance appeared for a short period of time in my wallet but then it started showing it as if I have 0 of that token.

The transaction can be seen here https://bscscan.com/tx/0x25e599bc4813e195fa9f6252af987f482f9ae6a25265b83a7cad8a7f962cb000

Also if I check my wallet assets on the blockchain I can see my tokens: https://bscscan.com/token/0xf7b4feb...?a=0x925768bB59f8b3E36897eC870cdf4788BA18f527

Tried metamask, coinbase and couple of more wallets, they all show 0 balance for the token. Again the balance was showing correctly for a few seconds before going to 0.

Am I doing something wrong or is it some kind of scam. I can see other people being able to sell their tokens

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad to say you bought a common scam on BSC.

Your balance is erased here: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe47662b0594f315e0d3a653ce0e9e965a52e703e66604f29ea0357453925d774

It's the same scam as outlined in this duplicate:

- [Lost tokens on pancakeswap](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153524/lost-tokens-on-pancakeswap/153554)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Could you please explain how did you find the transaction where the balance was erased? Just trying to learn.... Thank you

Comment: Look at the read tab of the token, find an address that is the "owner"/"controller", in these scams is usually a constant with a random set of letters. Clicked that address, looked at the transactions from that address a few minutes after you bought and it's there.

Comment: Yeah, I see. The whole increaseAllowance function looks dodgy.