# I purchased 60k shibarium tokens 8/19. 8/20 the value dropped 700% and contract address changed. What do I do?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, addresses, smart-contract-wallets, recover

I purchased Shabarium Tokens on 8/19/23. On 8/20/23 the contract address changed and the asset value under the old address dropped 700%. What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Comment: The bridge was compromised https://rekt.news/shibarium-bridge-rekt/. There's not much you can do. Meme projects could be fine for a short while but its price goes to zero after a while.