# REWARD!! PLEASE CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME ETH STUCK - I am a newbie trying to create a trading bot. and came across a tutorial, my 1.1eth stuck Metamask!

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, cpp-ethereum, bot

SORRY ABOUT THE GRAMMAR AND SPELLING I HAVENT SLEPT FOR ALLMOST 2 days BECAUSE OF THIS..

Here is a bit of a back story on why I have become a little desperate lately to find ways to make crypto faster than usual and I believe there are ways you can do this. I have read about it I was sure I found a way and all the guy wanted was more subs and views before it all dawned on me that it was a scam.

BACKSTORY-
On June 3rd I was part of huge unforeseen stressful situation in connection with the atomic wallet hack and lost over 600k due to their negligence and not users fault. My only regret is not moving the funds earlier which I had previously planned to however, this heart breaking situation occurred so unexpectable and sudden without my knowledge or a notification from Atomic. It was so astonishing that this had occurred that it left me literally paralyzed and speechless and filled with abundant of stress that you can't even imagine, it's like having someone taking the wind out of you leaving you defenseless and breathless metaphorically speaking, words can not express the trauma this circumstance has left me and my family in. Especially that I had all my private keys offline and a separate phone especially for this wallet which is hardly ever on. I unfortunately am part of the 5000 users who lost all their funds and I went into a complete depression mode for months and slowly starting to find the courage and trust in putting aside crypto again, this time in a proper air gapped hard wallet.

Fast forward present day -
I was engaging in doing some research on trading bots, especially these new defi Ethereum bots that are only possible if you are as quick as AI, something to do with transactions and mempools and  making your transaction fee higher so it takes you trade first, as for the code I have no clue how to read it properly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw&ab_channel=Web3Tutorials

I am the type that does not always believe in topic head titles as most are or turn out to be click bait, but some have had truth in them and it always depends how much you liquidity you have especially in terms of trading.

So I basically came across that video on Youtube and the guy on it appeared to be quite genuine and it had comments with people saying that this bot is till actually working now. Literally (THIS WEEK Sept 2023) the video displayed to have over 240 positive comments and not a single negative one. Until I actually realized this turned out to be a scam.
The only bad comments written was actually written by me, I wanted to make others aware of this and help others not make the same mistake.

I am really praying that somehow I can get my funds back as I still have full access to the code as the funds are still there.
CODE- https://pastebin.com/raw/3w4MiuPi
And can recompile it here- https://remixethereumcompiler.io/

I have 1.1 ETH in the smart contract which was created by my address, since the contract was created and deployed by me, would I be able to also modify it and redeploy the modded version or maybe place a function which can destroy the contract and extract all the funds back to the creators address. I was just scammed by Atomic Wallet over 600k and I am at a point of desperation trying to figure a way I can slowly make passive income.

I started watching the contract address over and over until I saw it produce some sort of income even though it wasn't much but it was something that was exciting to see and it made me think it was actually genuine, especially when I actually saw the first SWAP TX come through 0.0109eth. Then hours passed and nothing appeared to be happening now it had been 10 hours, 13 hours and still nothing. I then contacted him on telegram and he said it should be coming through constantly try press the start button again, and I did and now it said because of the Ethereum mainet being busy you need at least 1 eth. I needed around 0.0261654 to make it over 1 eth. So I said I may as well fund it as I made it this far already. Then the unforeseen happened believe it or not I hit the start again it and now said you need 2 eth, this is when it HIT me that something wasn't right and noticed that he changed a disclaimer on his Youtube video stating he fixed that bug, however he did not. And this created my anxiety to manifest which affected my sleep tremendously causing me not to be able to sleep or even function properly. It felt like the Atomic wallet experience all over again.

- https://etherscan.io/address/0x0bb0ff757a1f7403d10abe5fe7b14fba90d4b9e7

I am begging anyone who can help me take this out I will give them $200 for the help. I am so embarrassed and ashamed of myself I had tears in my eyes all morning as I felt like all  I do in life is a failure.

If someone wants to contact me directly my email is ah94gtr@hotmail.com me and my family will be forever grateful.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Sincerely,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel sorry for you, but the real thing is that you can't withdraw your funds, you got hacked.

This bot code is a **scam** and it succeeded in stealing a lot of funds from people.

This code makes the one who can withdraw the attacker's wallet address, it's not even a trading bot, it's just a **scam**.

If you want to know more about it, you can check out these links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264008/how-does-that-contract-parse-out-the-eth-wallet-address
https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/1577053856852156418

Don't trust anyone is the rule in the crypto field, 99% of bots are scams, and no one gives money for free.

I know how much that must hurt, both emotionally and financially, If you want to invest your money, you can try the things you know better, don't dream of fast earning.

Be strong and try to avoid this ordeal.

Answer (score 0):

I do feel for you, as it sounds like a horrible experience. But with maximum respect if you had taken time to "create" the bot you couldn't have been scammed as you'd have understood the code you were deploying. It is so dangerous to deploy code and send eth to a contract you don't understand. No one is giving away competitive bots.

This looks and sounds like a common scam. There is only one transaction that I could see as profit making and it isn't a swap on a pool, a trade or arbitrage. The function sig is `swap()` but it is just a transfer from an account that was dispersed that eth (mass dropped) 4 days ago, and the accounts only transaction is sending it to you after you have already deposited more than that. Seems like a bate charade to get someone to invest more money.

Skimming through I cannot see any calls to swaps on pool in the contract. Just functions that are obfuscated through inline asm but with comments that are total rubbish, talking about scanning the mem pool for uniswap transactions and loading them to memory, which isn't something that can be done on chain.

Suggest to read the following:

- [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)
- https://www.dlnews.com/articles/people-culture/crypto-users-fall-for-youtube-mev-trading-scams/

Wishing you luck and that you will make it back, but I don't think there is any way for you to recover that eth.

Comment: I thank you guys for not rubbing salt into the wounds like many do in some places like reddit.  I guess i messed up again.  I feel like im just one huge failure lately. Atomic was not my fault however i blame myself for trusting them. Im in the class action suit and if even get back 40k id be surprised.  Crypto i had saved up up until the AW had some from 2013 , i feel like i will never ever get the chance to get tot that level.

49.46ETH
10.006 BTC
22570 XRP

Comment: Much love. That is a heavy loss, and think it is totally normal to feel that way. First time market dumped and pulled out at the bottom just thought wow they got me, figured was smarter than that. But it's not about intelligence it is about fundamentally challenging a humans organic reactions to fear and greed because that is what is being played here. As much is hurts you can make it back but it's probably gonna come from a slow crawl because the space just punishes the impatient. Don't beat yourself up, just learn from it and let it be a story once you look back. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Bro. I suffered the same experience sometime in 2022. This made me to make a YouTube video to warn early crypto newbies about the uniswap bot scam. Lots of there video were reported and pulled down by YouTube. If you report such video, it would also be pulled down. You can watch this video where i explained my experience and how to avoid them https://youtu.be/ZlpXcKFCK_4