# fallen for a scam with fake ether can i recover from this smartcontract?

Tags: etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, scam

a friend got called and told that in order to receive his available funds he had to send 5.57 eth to a new wallet of his own on atomic wallet and he would receive 30 ether, he thought it was a scam but thought it would not be a scam if he sends it to his own wallet so he sent the money to that wallet and put it into a smart contract (this is his address) `0x5E25528827b08f2EF26dcF6db566B15e9CDc07B2` then they told him to have it available he needed to pay another 3500 to get it, then it ringed a bell and he called me, but I have no idea how to recover this since the ether isn't actual ether but a fake token, is he still able to get out of this? can he get his money back? This happened today.
can anyone help out? he has access to his atomic wallet and didn't share the recoveryphrase or anything, can someone investigate??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do) The link to the wallet you shared shows an EOA holding 35.57 ERC20 `ETH`, which like you said is just a fake token meant to look like Ethereum's native ETH. Do you have the transaction hash from when he sent the 5.57 ETH initially?

Comment: thanks for your reply but since this money is stuck in a smartcontract there is maybe a way out, this link just tells me to let it go to waste and that the money is gone, i think its still available because the contract cant be executed right now its still on the wallet there is the following thing, he sended btc to the wallet and converted it in a contract on the attomic wallet on this adress 1NwVaDuA36hw7nQ26cEWARx687Bi8LZ5E1 and it says the money is still there but he cant get it out

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, your friend swapped BTC for another token in a contract and now the token is stuck on the contract? Can you provide the smart contract address? Most likely the funds are unfortunately gone forever but I'll take a look at the code if it is a verified contract.

Comment: yes he swapped btc for a smartcontract i think: 0xa4f7D210cc491A531567EB042b43Bef8f332cd4b

Comment: The smart contract is unverified so I'm unsure of what the contract logic actually is. I'm sorry that y'all have lost some money, but for future reference, you and your friend should only interact with contracts you completely understand and that have verified source code.

Comment: yeah i understand that, he already tought it was a scam but in mind that he only send money to his own wallet he tought it would m,aybe be legit, is there a way to recover the contract or isnt that inposible? because when you look on the btc wallet it still has the money in it : 
1NwVaDuA36hw7nQ26cEWARx687Bi8LZ5E1 
this was the money send from the exchange to attom wallet