# I sent liquid staked eth to microstrategy for the Eth giveaway can I get it back?

Tags: ether

I thought that liquid staked eth was the same thing as eth and sent it in to Microstrategy for their Eth giveaway.  I didn’t think I just acted impulsively and I don’t know what to do now to get it back.

Comment: HI, I regret to inform you of this, but it seems that you have fallen prey to a scam. You may want to look at this Q&A written by a community member for questions like these: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do