# I dont know what this transation was for?

Tags: transactions, scam

I have this transaction on my metamast wallet.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd8087c11518988dc9c4517a907d5a4c32ea6fb1f6467c24426a83b48ead73ead

After this transaction, my Omi token disappeared. Was it a scam or anything else? Someone can explain this to me, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is executing the function `increaseAllowance(spender, value)` on the OMI contract, with this parameters:

- spender = 0x000022f3F10479cF34a0153F469CC3d06A880000
- value = 0xffffff...ffffff (something like a maximum amount)

So it is authorizing the spender full access to your OMI balance.

This function is required to execute when swapping tokens, the spender should be the swap contract.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could this function be part of a stake contract or I already lost the token? I mean,  I am not sure if it is a scam or I just use a stake contract that I don't remember. I just know that I don't my tokens:(

Comment: @TulioValentim The spender address `0x000022f3F10479cF34a0153F469CC3d06A880000 ` is flagged as a phishing scam, so my guess is that the token are lost.