# My contract is stuck not working on io

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain

I have .75 eth stuck in a contract when I hit withdraw from my solidity bot it says I don't have enough gas to pay...so I've put more eth in the meta mask wallet to cover it...but it still says the same thing....

Comment: The execution might need more gas for the withdrawal. If you need more help please post the contract code or verified address and chain.

Comment: there might be something wrong with contract or maybe the trxn is ailing, so metamask is showing 'fuunds not enough to pay gas' as precautionary.. 
if you have some dev issue.. ask here https://t.me/blockchainworldco/
its a group of web3 devs

Comment: If you followed some "bot tutorial" you were scammed. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do

Comment: It's definitely not a scam.. I can see my eth in the live contract...the problem was I didn't put enough ETH when deploying the contract.. it "code 3" error at time of deployment because it was .75 and said the market called for 1 for profitable frontruning....the contract went out anyway but has done nothing but sit due to not having enough ETH...now when I go to withdraw it errors again

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help.. its been almost 2 days and I'm just mindblown

Comment: Does sound like a scam. Something in the called method reverting so you'll never have enough gas.  If you copied a bot from youtube, it's likely a common scam.

Comment: @DeStacheDeStach3 Can you provide the contract source code? What network are you using? Without more details we can't help you.