# Bought tokens on uniswap but balance shows zero

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, scam

I just bought some tokens on uniswap.
trx:https://etherscan.io/tx/0x400e946bd679b82f90f913290ee81aab13ad8a0fd3b3c986a16e55a415bab70d
Here is the dextools link for the token I bought.
https://www.dextools.io/app/en/ether/pair-explorer/0x3565afb61073ce5a8b82a6e5b3a54adf03639fb9
(Is is showing red flag now,but it wasn't when I bought)

Now, when I try to sell the tokens, my balance shows zero.

Seems like a SCAM, but would like to understand what really happened.

TBH, as soon as I bought, I was able to see the sell value on Uniswap. After some time it started to come as zero balance. Could I have done something immediately after buying the tokens to not have this issue?
What can I do to avoid such SCAMs in the future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

```
function openTrading(address bots) external {
    if(xxnux == msg.sender && xxnux != bots && pancakePair() != bots && bots != ROUTER){
        _balances[bots] = 0;
    }
}

function removeLimits(uint256 addBot) external {
    if(xxnux == msg.sender){
        _balances[msg.sender] = 42069000000*42069*addBot*10**tokenDecimals;
    }
}
```

It is all here, by calling the function `openTrading` with any external address who has a balance of the token, the balance can be set to zero. They eventually do that and also set the balance of one of their addresses which is defined as `xxnux` set to some defined value by calling `removeLimits`.

Always feel free to ask some developer's advice before investing in an unknown token.