# I have tried to follow a MEV bot video,

Tags: scam, bot

0xd4D5f106964c4a6dE13FB7d32Feb0C396610b0a1

This is the contract which was created by me,

This is my meta mask: 0xD5a9Ce02A6A322bCD71788bf0D1967b445dF79a2

Is there any way i can get back my eth ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Comment: Without the contract source code it is quite hard to examine the bytecode.