# Airdrop reward in smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum

Dear Ethereum Community,

Is there really an airdrop functionality in the Ethereum Smart Contract, which will end on 18th of February?
If yes, where can I reach the airdrop rules?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
László

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not true.

***It's likely a scam mechanism utilizing tokens theft or wallet draining.***

If you'd like to participate in a real airdrop, check the official resources.

---

E.g. Kucoin has put together a list of real airdrops for February 2024: https://www.kucoin.com/blog/the-best-crypto-airdrops-for-february-2024