# Bought tokens which appear to be in my wallet on bscscan, but my metamask wallet says 0

Tags: tokens, uniswap, bscscan

I swapped some tokens on uniswap, with just a small amt to test, and it appears that the tokens are in my wallet when I look on bscscan:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0a2380770b1ffff572c634866238565960ed6528cb6a73bc82b990e0408ca7a4

And they show under my wallet:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x1Bd9EdD1C8959882B7AE95578Cd23548fD304e03

But when I click on the token in my wallet (on bscscan)  it seems to say both, that I have the tokens, but also that I have 0 tokens:

https://bscscan.com/token/0x4070b1f89ac16efe0e7f035b2a04284bcd5c220e?a=0x1Bd9EdD1C8959882B7AE95578Cd23548fD304e03

I can also see my address as one of the 'token holders'.

I'm confused why it's showing 0 and also why they're not showing in my metamask web extension.  I've custom imported the token, but nothing shows at all.  I've tried again and it says it's already imported.

On my phone, I can import the token, but it says 0 balance.

I know this is a bsc token (not eth), but I noticed some similar issues here from other users. I'm not 100% convinced mine is a scam, as I can see that I am a holder.

Any info was would greatly appreciated.  I learn loads from others questions/answers, but I am confused here!  Thank you!
PS. Sorry this is so long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

Adding token manually in Metamask should make them visible. I checked the transactions, the tokens are in the above wallet.

Follow this link:
https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-display-tokens-in-MetaMask

This is the token you would want to import:
0x4070b1F89Ac16efE0E7F035b2A04284Bcd5C220E

Comment: Thanks, but I did import manually and I still can't see the token at all on the MM web extension.  It imported into my phone (on metamask), but it says the amt is 0 and therefore I can't sell/swap etc.  When I put my address into poocoin.app it says I have 0 tokens also.  I just can't seem to see them anywhere except on bscscan.

Answer (score 0):

You got scammed.

If you go to decode the token implementation, https://bscscan.com/address/0x262C5FB5bcC0ff56b73B4421C85f61370F4e2A79#code.

we decompiled the code, and see this `Approve` function:  https://app.dedaub.com/decompile?fileId=null&fileType=null&line=129
it calls another function, `0x54c`, which sets your balance to whatever the owner like to.

Attacker tx to set your balance to 0:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb5fca877ef46ea1ccfa5993a007701983e52c926a56a114f9a1e9aa1b297c242

Sorry for the loss. Nowadays, there are lots of these kinds of scammy contracts out there. Please ape before reading the contract code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm glad I only chucked $20 in then!  I'm assuming my wallet wouldn't be comprised by this at all would it?  Also, out of interest, is there a way to check this issue before I purchase?  Anyway, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, if it was a scam how is it that on coinmooner there appeared to be lots of buys and sells happening at the time I bought?  Can this be faked?  Cheers