# Shows I am a holder in Etherscan but balance is zero

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, scam

I purchased a token, and my balance for the token is showing as zero. I believe it is a scam token, but I see sales from older wallets that look legitimate (as well as exit transactions from bots).

Details here

- [Purchased token](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x195b93e9b6f784fd2332160e950d9d0421e29d29147cc837966166b6e7691cf9)
- [Shows I am a holder of token in token contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0x19e8e359c65e794578df4284c10cb943ab6b087c#balances)
- [Example of non-bot looking wallets exiting position](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b54c700618eb7a394fca651961616b63b631e3b4bcc6af98cefad4786d22c68)

I appreciate it if anyone can look into this and see if it is possible for me to exit this token somehow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 2):

You got scammed actually. This kind of scam token is everywhere on-chain. There's no sophisticated logic inside the contract.

If you check the source code, the owner can remove your balance by calling `addBot` (https://etherscan.io/token/0x19e8e359c65e794578df4284c10cb943ab6b087c#code#L42)

Below is the transaction sent by the owner and put your balance to 0.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54aa5e54786b67fd5bdc41a5df27c8059b4add970e5fa2edd49d5c8ac4d96f24

Sorry for the loss. Please, if you want to ape a shit coin, check the code first. This can easily be prevented.