My trading platform is demanding 11000 to get acces to my 239000 usdt is this true
MC UPBIT.COM. trading platform doing btc/usdt contracts. They are asking me to depost 11000 to withdraw 60000

It's a scam, read this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-or-uniswap-what-to-do
